# How to detect URLs requested by iPhone / iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, networking

Basically I need to detect what url calls does an app do?

Dunno if I have to setup proxy or is there HTML5 / Native library for that. Thanks

Comment: For iPhone simulator you can install any network monitoring s/w for your mac .. [Wireshark](http://wireshark.en.softonic.com/mac)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using Charles Proxy for that, great tool: http://www.charlesproxy.com

You could also have a look at Pony Debugger by Square: https://github.com/square/PonyDebugger. There is a good introduction video here: http://cocoaheads.tv/ponydebugger-by-jay-thrash/